# What is the best feature detector and descriptor extractor to use for disease diagnosis?

Tags: algorithm, opencv

My Android application, as part of my final project, utilizes OpenCV for digital image processing (disease detection and classification, to be exact). Specifically, I used SIFT algorithm to match features from two different images, but I found out that the disease detection is inaccurate and inconsistent.

I would like to ask: what do you think is the best algorithm to use for this purpose? Specifically, what algorithm ensures both consistency and accuracy regardless of illumination, orientation, rotation, and scaling?

Edit: I wish to compare, for example:
[this image of a durian trunk showing severe image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPNQF.jpg) and [this image showing a similar feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbeG7.jpg). What would be the best algorithm to use for comparing two different images with SIMILAR features?

Comment: strongly depends on the kind of images and diseases you are talking about. If it is a scientific project you should try ALL kind of features/descriptors and classification methods you can. Or from intuition or expert knowledge you could choose feature types (like edges or color) that are characteristic for that disease

Comment: @Micka - The source image is captured using the camera, and it will be compared with the samples stored in the database. What would be the best algorithm to use so that consistency and accuracy of matching is maintained?

Comment: it really depends on very concrete details, unless you want to find/compare exactly identical looking objects. Post sample images or you CANT get any concrete help.

Comment: Had a class some years ago about medical image processing: what we usually did was first a fourier transform then some calculations (e.g. to highlight only edges) then transform back and use Bayes classifier. It's also important that the images are aligned correctly or you have to do that first. Then other things come into consideration, like X-ray are rigid but MRI can have "a lot" of distortion.